# Disable and enable edittext in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I've a `ListView` with `EditText` in a row layout. I want the `EditText` to be disabled when created and to make it editable on button "EDIT" click. After updating the text, the user can click "SAVE" button to make it uneditable again. I'm facing an issue in making the corresponding  `EditText` editable. It becomes enabled but does not get focus and the soft keyboard also does not appear. Am I doing something wrong here?

```css
//Adapter class button click:-

 holder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.count.setEnabled(true);
                holder.count.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                holder.count.setFocusable(true);
                holder.count.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(holder.count, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
                holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
 holder.save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.count.setEnabled(false);
                holder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.save.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

```html
//row layout xml:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffb3ff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="edit"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You have created a list for adapter.If you are using bean class then a new field add "edit" type boolean and set true and false after click and provide editable of EditText this variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple actually. I just needed to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"` in my Manifest's activity. After that its working good with `setEnabled()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this snippet of code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(holder.count, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

with

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

and after this you will have to give focus to another View in the list.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
holder.count.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: I tried `setClickable` also but when I touch edittext to change text, it becomes uneditable. @Rissmon

Answer (score 0):

you are encountering the same problem i encountered some days before when i was creating sample browser for myself.First of all do not use setEditable(false) because once focus of edit text is removed, it would not allow you to type even if you set it to focusable again.

use this instead of setEditable(false):

```
holder.count.setFocus(false);
holder.count.setClickable(false);
holder.count.setCursorVisible(false);
```

and when you want to enable your textview:

```
holder.count.setFocus(true);
holder.count.setFocusInTouchMode(true);
holder.count.setClickable(true);
holder.count.setCursorVisible(true);
```

if it works let me know in comments...